# Help me understand Bitcoin analytics

Tags: blockchain, api

I'm trying to use the Blocktrail API to look at the oldest Bitcoin addresses to create a info graph piece - besides looking at historical transactions, what else would be good for me to analyze?

\\ to be specific, what could I use analytics for with Bitcoin
- besides looking at addresses

Comment: Hi Lisa, I'm afraid that such an open question doesn't work well on Bitcoin.SE. Perhaps you should check out our [tour] and [ask] to get more information about how our site works and what kind of questions and answers we collect here.

Comment: What are you looking to analyze.

Answer (score 1):

I'm particularly curious about analytics for addresses that include taint-of-taint data, specifically I'm wondering if its possible to extract useful information from an address that's interacted with coins 2 hops away from say, a betting site. I think this could have many implications for researchers looking to do some other kind of node/graph analysis as well.